# Find an nth element from the end of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

i looked at this challenge from codesignal (nthelementfromtheend) and put my code (below) in a test site

```
function nthElementFromTheEnd(l, n) {
if (n > l.length){
    return -1;
}else{

// console.log();
let index = l.length - n;
// console.log(index);
// console.log(l[index]);
return l[index];
}
}

let l = [1, 2, 3, 4];
let n=7;
nthElementFromTheEnd(l, n);
```

results seem to pass the test site, but not codesignal.

open links below in new tab

[challenge](https://app.codesignal.com/challenge/o9QW9r6JcBKqceGBq)

[tester](https://www.webtoolkitonline.com/javascript-tester.html)

[array length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length)

Comment: `open links below in new tab` no - not sure if this will "pass" the test, but, if you try to access the 7th element of an array that has length 4, what is the resultant value? perhaps that's what you need your code to return - also, should `n` be 0 or 1 based - i.e. ... if `n===1` should the result be 4 or 3?

Comment: OK, having read the challenge, ignore the above :p (really, I should not have had to go to an external site to understand the parameters of your question) - and the comment at the top of the challenge *"Singly-linked lists are already defined with this interface:"* suggests you should be using singly-linked lists?

Answer (score 1):

You need to analyze the input that is coming into the function. `l` represents a singly-linked list. This doesn't exist natively in JavaScript, but it has been re-created using an object, as the comment describes:

```
// Singly-linked lists are already defined with this interface:
function ListNode(x) {
    this.value = x;
    this.next = null;
}
```

In the first test, the input that comes to the function looks like this:

```
ListNode {
    value: 1,
    next: ListNode {
        value: 2,
        next: ListNode {
            value: 3,
            next: null
        }
    }
}
```

So this is not as simple as returning a particular index from an array, because the function is not receiving an array but an object. You have to navigate the data structure continually checking for `next` values. There are probably more efficient ways to do this, but here's an example that at least passes the 8 sample tests:

```
function nthElementFromTheEnd(l, n) {
    let values = [];
    let node = l;

    while (node) {
        values.push(node.value);
        node = node.next;
    }

    let len = values.length;

    if (n > len) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return values[len-n];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick here is in the comment indicating the interface of a singly-linked lists.

```
// Singly-linked lists are already defined with this interface:
// function ListNode(x) {
//   this.value = x;
//   this.next = null;
// }
//
```

So you need to use `l.next` and `l.value` to navigate and get values from the linked list.

Here is a possible solution (not optimized):

```
function nthElementFromTheEnd(l, n) {
    // find the length of the linked list
    let len = 1;
    let c = l;
    while (c.next) {
        len++;
        c = c.next;
    }

    if (n > len) {
        return -1
    }
    else {
        // iterate linked list and get desired value (len-n)
        let i = 0;
        while (i < len-n){
            l = l.next;
            i++;
        }

        return l.value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function nthElementFromTheEnd(l, n) {
var input = l;
var rev= input.reverse();
   let value = rev[n-1];
   if(value){
     return value;
   }
   else
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: for a start, you're mutating the incoming array (not just locally in the function, you're actually mutating the array passed in)

Comment: changed. is that okay?

Comment: that hasn't changed anything ... now you have `l`, `input` and `rev` all referring to the same mutated array

Comment: Assuming the code and the changes are ok, there is another issue with this answer. While this code snippet may solve the problem, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/2648551) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!